# Set existing IAM role as Default role-type in Redshift Cluster using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-redshift

I've been trying to set existing IAM role as Default role type in AWS Redshift using terraform but with no luck.
[image]

I can do it from UI but can't find a way to do it via terraform. Can someone suggest if terraform supports it and how it can be done?

To test this feature, I've run following tf code(hard-coded some values to test just role type feature):

```
resource "aws_redshift_cluster" "test" {
  cluster_identifier      = "test"
  node_type          = "ra3.xlplus"
  cluster_type       = "single-node"
#  cluster_number_of_nodes = 1

  database_name   = "rrraineytest"
  master_username = "Randomtest12"
  master_password = "Randomtest12"
#
  cluster_subnet_group_name                = "dev-redshift-sng"
  skip_final_snapshot       = true
#  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-01eb5ea5e4dcr317b"]
  iam_roles = ["arn:aws:iam::826532334455:role/phoenix-redshift-role"]

  #  redshift_subnet_group_name = module.vpc.redshift_subnet_group
#  0e6c195
}
```

It creates cluster but issue is that there's no way to pass role-type(At least I can't find it in tf docs)
Link: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/redshift_cluster

Comment: " been trying " - if so where is your TF code? Why it does not work? What are the errors?

Comment: @Marcin: Code is up there.

Comment: What is the error you see? Is there any terraform command output to add to the question?

Comment: @MarkoE There's no error in this code. It'll run and create cluster and attach mentioned IAM role. Issue is that I can't find a way to pass ```role-type``` in this tf code? In  another words, how I can make this IAM role default role for cluster as shown in screenshot.

Comment: Yup, seems you are right, I wasn't aware of the additional option. Unfortunately, it seems it's still not available in Terraform: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22819.